# Trajectory of light rays in a mirror polygon

Tags: real-analysis, euclidean-geometry, polygons, reflection

> Given a general polygon and we are given a ray of light bouncing between the sides of the polygon where each side is a mirror. they hit at points $P_1,P_2...$, we define $\alpha_i$ to be the smaller of the angles between $P_iP_{i+1}$ and the side $P_i$ is on. Is it possible that $\alpha_1>\alpha_i$ for all $i>1$?
> We assume the trajectory never touches a corner of the polygon.

We can notice the light ray can not have a periodic path since it would have the angle $\alpha_1$ again.
But in general, paths of light inside mirror polygons need not be periodic.

Comment: Is not quite complete the question (at least I don't fully understand what are you asking). But if I choose as a polygon an square, and I place the beam source in the center (so fixing here my system of coordinates) in such a way the axis are perpendicular to side of the square, and I choose to shoot the light beam at an angle $\alpha = 0°$, the ray will hit perpendicularly the sides of the square kept contained always in one of the coordinate system's axis, so doing a periodic orbit inside a polygon, which is against your last paragraph (if there is a question there, this is a counterexample)

Comment: I mean that the ray starts from one one the sides, in you case the first angle it makes with a side is $90^o$ and the same for the second, so the first angle in not the largest angle.

Comment: I suggest you to redact explicetely (maybe with a picture or draw), what are you thinking when imaging your question situation. In general, you cannot model a ray hitting a corner of the mirror polygon since is not differentiable, like $|x|$ at $x=0$, so more detail is needed.

Comment: since in reflections bouncings are symmetrical with the normal vector to the mirror in the incidence point, if I call $\theta$ the angle between the light ray and this perpendicular vector, then I will have that the inteenal angle made by the incident and relfected rays as a corner will be $\gamma = 2\theta$, both different from the angle made by the rays and the mirror $\beta=90°-\theta$ such as $2\beta+\gamma=180°$... Which one correspond to you angles $\alpha$?? I could manage to make $\beta$ being bigger than $\gamma$ so for me the definition is still ambiguous.

Comment: I intend for the one between the side and ray $90^o-\theta$

Comment: Yes. An initial shot at 90° into any polygon that fulfills the aperiodic trajectory condition is a trivial solution, if you always take the smaller angle and know 90° doesn't happen again. Or what am I missing?

Comment: Well, yes, but this is more of an edge case, I would like a solution which works for a non-$90^o$ angle.

Comment: Confirm if I get correctly the spirit of your question: you are asking if it is possible to have bounces that become progressively and irreversibly flatter, that is, the ray is becoming more and more parallel to the sides it is hitting

Comment: Yes, you understood it correctly.

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/764412/can-we-trap-a-light-ray-in-a-prism-in-geometric-optics

A similar (unanswered!) question from the physics perspective might help to understand the motivation.

Answer (score 3):

[image: An irregular octagon]

Consider this arrangement of $8$ mirrors (the thick black lines). The three horizontal mirrors are on $y=0,y=1,y=2$ and the three vertical mirrors are on $x=0,y=2,x=\beta $, where $\beta >2$ is irrational.

The red arrow shows a light ray making any angle $\alpha_1>45^o$ with mirror $L$. The direction of $L$ can be adjusted at will. The crucial thing is that the ray is at $45^o$ to the horizontal.

The ray then enters and is trapped in the blue region. The path is then aperiodic and then the ray will never escape back along the red path. Therefore all further $\alpha_i =45^o$.

PROOF

The ray first hits a mirror at $(3,0)$. Between this hit and subsequent hits on a horizontal mirror the ray will travel an integer distance in a vertical direction. It will of course travel the same integer distance in a horizontal direction.

When this distance is $D-3$, the $x$-coordinate of the hitting point will be $D$ if $D\le \beta$ but $2\beta -D$ if $\beta <D\le 2\beta$.

Therefore the $x$-coordinate of any hitting point will be either  $D-2n\beta $ or $2n\beta -D$, for some integer $n$. It will **never** again be $D$.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, doen't the ray pass throught the corner of the horizontal mirror at $y=2$? otherwise there would be an entire interval through which it could exit?

Comment: Yes, it grazes the corner. Or, if you prefer, suppose the mirror's silvering to be removed at the single point $(1,2)$.

Comment: The same applies at $(2,1)$.

Answer (score 1):

In a square, it may not be possible, since $\alpha_i = 90-\alpha_{i-1}$ OR $\alpha_i = \alpha_{i-1}$.

In a equilateral triangle also it may not be possible, $\alpha_i = 120-\alpha_{i-1}$ OR $\alpha_i = 60+\alpha_{i-1}$.

In a general regular $n$-gon, $\alpha_i = \ell \frac{360}{n} + \alpha_{i-1}$ OR $\alpha_i = 180 - \ell \frac{360}{n} - \alpha_{i-1}$ for some $0 \leq \ell \leq n-1$.

Since the possibilities are finitely many, the angles will repeat.
Although not sure if initial angle $\alpha_1$ will be part of the repeating angles in $\{\alpha_i\}$.

Based on this intuition: I suggest you try to construct polygon with irrational angles and rational angles or co-prime angles. In such a case you will atleast have aperiodic angles $\{\alpha_i\}$. May be try a triangle first.

Cheers man !